# How to format the Stack Exchange "feed"?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, meta

I just made an account here on Stack Exchange, so I apologize if I haven't quite learned the etiquette around here. I also so far have only used the mobile app for SE, not the website, so this question may not apply outside of the app.

So long story short, I decided to jump from Reddit to SE since I have found that SE seems to offer what I look for most in a community (mostly tech-oriented, Q&A format). Thing is, I'm trying to get a "front page" kind of like reddit, where it shows the hottest posts for the subreddits that I'm subscribed to. Here on the app, I see a "Feed" section where I can view "hot questions", but they seem to be pulled from all communities. Is there any way to see a list of recent/hot/active questions for *just* the communities I'm subscribed to within the app?

I'm also seeing that not only can I join a community, but I can also "pin" it... What's the difference?